# DataGrid enable text wrapping of columns with AutoGenerateColumns=true

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on an WPF MVVM application. I have a DataGrid, which is binded to a DataTable. `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true.

However, I want to wrap the text of a column to 2 or 3 lines if needed. Currently, when I scroll the DataGrid, when the first column's text is longer, the first column expands as much as it needs and the last column is not seen anymore or is cut.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinHeight" Value="50" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinWidth" Value="60" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Grid:

```
<Grid
    Width="800"
    Height="500"
    Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid.Resources>
        //code
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid
        Name="Map"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        AutoGeneratingColumn="Map_AutoGeneratingColumn"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeRows="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"
        FontStretch="Normal"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MapDataTable}" />
```

I omitted things that are not relevant to the question.

Here is what I have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinHeight" Value="50" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinWidth" Value="60" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
               <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Attempt 2:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinHeight" Value="50" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.MinWidth" Value="60" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="ItemsControl.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Both of them don't work. What is the correct way to fix the text wrapping? `AutoGenerateColumns` MUST be true.

Comment: Why AutoGenerateColumns must be true ?

Comment: I am adding columns to the DataTable dynamically during runtime.

Comment: Setting the ColumnWidth="*" doesn't help ?

Comment: I don't think so, no. I can't set it to "*" in the Style and that is not what I intend to do. I want the column cells to be multiline.

Comment: Could you please share related DataGrid code also ?

Comment: Yes, just edited the question.

Comment: Note that you should never set the DataGrid.Height to Auto. This will disable the vertical scroll bar as the DataGrid is now allowed to stretch infinitely. This will disable UI virtualization, which means your DataGrid will load ALL items immediately instead of loading only visible items. This will have a significant performance impact. Additionally you will have problems to view all items as there is no ScrollViewer to allow scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have realized modifying the column header does not modify the column. The solution is to listen to the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event and modify the generated columns selectively.

I see that you are already listening to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event. You simply have to modify the event handler to apply a `TextBlock` style to the text columns.

First define a `Style` that targets `TextBlock` and enables text wrapping:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="Map_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Then go to the `AutogeneratingColumn` event handler `Map_AutoGeneratingColumn` and filter the text columns to set their initial width and to apply the previously defined `TextBlock` style:

```
private void Map_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  if (e.Column is DataGridTextColumn textColumn)
  {
    textColumn.ElementStyle = dataGrid.FindResource(typeof(TextBlock)) as Style;
    e.Column.Width = 100;
  }
}
```